# CSS3 Resizing div from all borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a way to be able to resize div from all borders ?

Example

```
<div>
....
</div>

<style>
div{
 resize: both;   /* Options: horizontal, vertical, both */
 overflow: auto; /* fix for Safari */
}
</style>
```

will add a handle at lower bottom corner for resizing,

but how to be able to resize from any borders ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible at all. This is a browser-dependent feature which does not work in IE at all. See [description](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp): you are allowed only to set up the dimensions of resizing, but not the position of handles.

You should implement this function in JavaScript by yourself for all browsers if there is no life without it.